# How to call a constructor with dynamic amount of arguments?

Tags: javascript

I have a constructor and I don't know the number of arguments it needs, for instance:

```
function someCtor(a,b,c){
   var that = this;
   that.a = a;
   that.b = b;
   that.c = c;
}
```

I need to create a function which will return the instance of that constructor with a dynamic amount of arguments:

```
function makeNew(ctor, arguments){
    // this doesn't work, but it shows what I'm trying to achieve
    return new ctor.apply(arguments);
}
```

I want to use the function to pass the dynamic arguments to the constructor like below:

```
var instanceOfCtor = makeNew(someCtor, [5,6,7]);
```

How to implement this function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Note:** See the ES2015 compatibility note at the end.

You do it by first creating an object setting its underlying prototype to the object the `prototype` property on the constructor refers to via `Object.create`, then calling the constructor via `Function#apply`:

```
function makeNew(ctor, arguments){
    var obj = Object.create(ctor.prototype);
    var rv = ctor.apply(obj, arguments);
    return rv && typeof rv === "object" ? rv : obj;
}
```

Note the bit of fiddling at the end, so we're emulating the `new` operator correctly: When you call a constructor via `new`, if it returns a non-`null` object reference, that ends up being the result of the `new` expression; if it returns anything else (or nothing), the object created by `new` is the result. So we emulate that.

Even on pre-ES5 browsers, you can emulate enough of `Object.create` to do that:

```
if (!Object.create) {
    Object.create = function(proto, props) {
        if (typeof props !== "undefined") {
            throw new Error("The second argument of Object.create cannot be shimmed.");
        }
        function ctor() { }
        ctor.prototype = proto;
        return new ctor;
    };
}
```

---

#### ES2015 Compatibility Note

If the constructor you're calling was created via ES2015's `class` syntax, the above won't work, because you can't call ES2015 `class` constructors that way. For example:

```js
class Example {
    constructor(a, b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}

const e = Object.create(Example.prototype);
Example.apply(e, [1, 2]); // TypeError: Class constructor Example cannot be invoked without 'new' (or similar)
```

The good news is that will only happen on an ES2015+-compatible JavaScript engine, and only if the constructor was created via `class`; the bad news is that it can happen.

So how do you make your `makeNew` bulletproof?

It turns out this is quite easy, because ES2015 also added `Reflect.construct`, which does exactly what you want `makeNew` to do but does it in a way that's compatible with both `class` constructors and `function` constructors. So you can feature-detect `Reflect.construct` and use it if it's present (ES2015 JavaScript engine, so a constructor might have been created with `class`) and fall back to the above if it's not there (pre-ES2015 engine, there won't be any `class` constructors around):

```
var makeNew; // `var` because we have to avoid any ES2015+ syntax
if (typeof Reflect === "object" && Reflect && typeof Reflect.construct === "function") {
    // This is an ES2015-compatible JavaScript engine, use `Reflect.construct`
    makeNew = Reflect.construct;
} else {
    makeNew = function makeNew(ctor, arguments){
        var obj = Object.create(ctor.prototype);
        var rv = ctor.apply(obj, arguments);
        return rv && typeof rv === "object" ? rv : obj;
    };
}
```

That's pure ES5 syntax, so runs on ES5 engines, but uses ES2015's `Reflect.construct` if it's present.